# Azure SQL DB MI doesn't support Windows Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

Microsoft documentation states that "Azure SQL Database Managed Instance" doesn't support Windows Authentication, it has to be either SQL auth or AAD auth. Could someone please help me understand why Managed instance doesn't support Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 2):

There is a statement on github that is just 3 hours old:

> Windows Authentication unfortunately is not supported (not
>   implemented) feature for Managed Instance at this time. We might
>   consider supporting it sometimes in the future, however please note
>   that no public statements can be provided at this time. Please review
>   the officially documented list of supported and unsupported features
>   here:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-features.
>   Thank you.

It appears that they simply have not implemented it.